# Android how can i get the image button's id programmatically?

Tags: java, android, imagebutton, android-button

I created image button and I set that's image programmatically with this code:

```
myButton1[0][0].setImageResource(R.drawable.mayin2);
```

And I want to get that image's id or name from another method. How can i call image button's image's id or name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that directly, it's just a reference to a drawable resource that gets retrieved, but the integer value isn't retained. One thing you could do is store the reference as a tag on the View:

```
myButton1[0][0].setImageResource(R.drawable.mayin2);
myButton1[0][0].setTag(R.drawable.mayin2);
```

Then you could retrieve it with:

```
Integer resourceID = (Integer) myButton1[0][0].getTag("resource_id");
```

EDIT: Alternately, if you need to store multiple tags, define an ID in your `values` folder (create some XML file, maybe `ids.xml`) like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="resource" type="id" />
</resources>
```

Then set a tag with that ID:

```
myButton1[0][0].setImageResource(R.drawable.mayin2);
myButton1[0][0].setTag(R.id.resource, R.drawable.mayin2);
```

Then retrieve by that same ID:

```
Integer resourceID = (Integer) myButton1[0][0].getTag(R.id.resource);
```

Comment: Thanks, I know i can do it with that way but i've already used setTag method for another thing so i can't use setTag. Is there another possible way?

Comment: Can I use myButton1[0][0].setTag(123, R.drawable.mayin2); and Integer resourceID = (Integer) myButton1[0][0].getTag(123); instead of creating a new xml file?

Comment: Yes, but it's not guaranteed to be unique. In practice I don't think you'd ever have an issue doing it that way though.

Comment: I created ids.xml file but compiler gave a error; Error: String types not allowed (at 'resources' with value ''). And I also tried to give a random id instead of creating xml file then compiler gave a error too. 05-01 04:47:28.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2201): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The key must be an application-specific resource id.

Comment: Sorry, that's my mistake. I've edited my answer, just take out the `format="integer"` attribute. And yeah, apparently it *is* required to make a defined ID in XML.